# Get the date three days from today with BusyBox date

Tags: linux, docker, shell, alpine-linux

I need to the date three days from today. On CentOS, I can run the below command.

```bash
date -I -d "-3 days"
```

Which outputs

```
2022-07-02
```

I need the same inside my Docker container which is running on *Alpine Linux 3.14.6v*.

When I execute the same command I am getting the error:

> date: invalid date '-3 days'

Anyone knows the workaround for this?

Comment: Try: `date -d 'now -3 days'`

Comment: @F.Hauri ```date: invalid date 'now -3 days'```

Comment: @darecoder I was wondering if you ever figure this out without installing extra packages?

Comment: @Eazy Posting answer!

Answer (score 4):

A way to do it could be to use a bit of arithmetic on a timestamp, then translate the timestamp back into a date:

```bash
date -d "@$(( $(date +%s) - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 ))"
```

---

Given

```bash
docker run --rm alpine:3.14 sh -c 'date; 
  date -d "@$(( $(date +%s) - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 ))"'
```

It would yield:

```
Tue Jul  5 11:51:31 UTC 2022
Sat Jul  2 11:51:31 UTC 2022
```

Comment: The problem (see [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206540/date-d-command-fails-on-docker-alpine-linux-container)) is that the alpine-linux version of date is "limited".  Option 1 (per the above link):  install [coreutils](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/coreutils).  Option 2: Another solution might be to create a shell function that does the equivalent of `date -d 'now -3 days'`.  SUGGESTION: If you choose Option 2, I would *DEFINITELY* name the shell function something *BESIDES* "date".

Answer (score 0):

From StackExchange.com:

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206540/date-d-command-fails-on-docker-alpine-linux-container
>
> BusyBox/Alpine version of date doesn't support -d options, even if the
> help is exatly the same in the Ubuntu version as well as in others
> more fat distros.
>
> To work with -d options you just need to add coreutils package

Comment: don't want to add a whole package just for ```-d``` option. @paulsm4

Answer (score 0):

The below code snipped worked for me on alpine linux.

```
ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS=86400000
PLUS_DAYS=3
PLUS_DAYS_IN_MILLIS=$((ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS * PLUS_DAYS))
NEW_DATE_IN_MILLIS=`expr ${CURRENT_DATE_IN_MILLIS} + ${PLUS_DAYS_IN_MILLIS}`
local newDate=`date -d @$(  echo " ${NEW_DATE_IN_MILLIS} / 1000" | bc) '+%Y-%m-%d'`
echo $newDate
```